# Using gulp-haml: how to use filters?

Tags: coffeescript, sass, gulp, haml

We're using a Gulpfile-based build system which transpiles HAML to HTML.

In some cases, we would like to allow the developers to use several filters directly from the HAML files, such as `:coffeescript`, `:sass` or `:less`.

We tried `gulp-haml`, `gulp-haml-coffee`, `gulp-haml-coffee-compile` but none were able to transpile correctly the `:coffeescript` blocks.

Ideally, we would like a first pass of filter to "in-place" replace `:coffeescript` / `:sass` blocks, then run the HAML transpilation pass. What would then be the recommended way to do so?